# Programing a Loop and saving to a variable

Tags: matlab

I am trying to write some code that saves the result of 10 equations to be stored into a variable, and then the variable is cleared.

For example

```
{
Run Equation  A= 1+1 
Save A to variable X. 
Run Equation A 10 times. 
}
```

After the 10th time,

```
{
Run equation C = f(X)
Clear X.
}
```

Can anyone help on how to write this or what I should be looking at.

Comment: It's not clear what this is meant to do. Can you give a more concrete example, and what you are trying to achieve? what function is `f(X)`? Which values should `X` take? The way you have worded the question, `X` should always be `2`!

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. I suggest you familiarize yourself with [MATLAB's language fundamentals](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/language-fundamentals.html) and make an attempt to solve your problem on your own.

Answer (score 0):

```
A=2;
for ii = 1:10 %// set up a loop
    X(ii) = A+1; %// calculate your things
end
C = x.^2; %// Calculate more things
clear x %// clear the temporary variable.
```

The interesting bits for you are the `x(ii)` syntax as for vector indexing and the `clear` command to remove variables from the workspace.